# Limit number of relationship in ManyToManyField in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am using ManyToMany relationship in my code in a scenario where i have showrooms and their categories. Now a showroom can fall into maximum three categories and i have to validate it while saving. Below is my code:

```
##models.py
class Showrooms(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    contact_person = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    offer = models.TextField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Categories, null=True, blank=True,    related_name='categories')


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'showrooms'
        verbose_name_plural = "showrooms"


class Categories(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = showroom_upload_path, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'showroom_categories'
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category
```

everything is working fine except i am not able to put validation on number of categories per showroom. And i am not using it in views but just wanna to do it in admin.

Please help

Thanks

#### Edits

Ok.. I have solved my issue. I created a form in forms.py

```
class ShowroomsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Showrooms

    def clean(self):
        categories = self.cleaned_data.get('categories')
        if categories and categories.count() > 3:
            raise ValidationError('Maximum three categories are allowed.')

        return self.cleaned_data
```

and added it to admin.py like below:

```
class ShowroomsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ShowroomsForm


admin.site.register(Showrooms, ShowroomsAdmin)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django manytomany restriction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21353038/django-manytomany-restriction)

Comment: Oh yes.. You are absolutely right but i couldn't find it out while i was looking for it :(

Comment: No problem, I didn't notice that you have already figured it out by now. Good for you :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All I needed was to create a model form:

```
class ShowroomsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Showrooms
    
    def clean(self):
        categories = self.cleaned_data.get('categories')
        if categories and categories.count() > 3:
            raise ValidationError('Maximum three categories are allowed.')
    
        return self.cleaned_data
```

and added it to admin.py like below:

```
class ShowroomsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ShowroomsForm
    

admin.site.register(Showrooms, ShowroomsAdmin)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could define a clean() method on your model an raise a validation error whenever a showroom gets assigned to more than 3 categories.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

Comment: I tried that but it was showing errors. Logically, to validate categories first we need to have a showroom object which is not possible without saving it. IMO form would be a better place. What do you think?

Comment: Hey.. I have solved my issue. I have edited my question to show the answer. It was very easy :) BTW thanks for your time and help

Comment: @RaakeshKumar Go ahead and answer your own question, this is highly encouraged. That way we can upvote the answer and compare it to other answers, and this question will be considered answered by the site.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and used @Rakesh Kumar's solution. But then I got an error

```bash
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form JobsForm needs updating.
```

The problem was that Rashid's form didn't have any form fields.
So I modified his solution just a little.

`forms.py` - I added fields

```py
class ShowroomsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Showrooms
        fields = "__all__"
    
    def clean(self):
        categories = self.cleaned_data.get('categories')
        if categories and categories.count() > 3:
            raise ValidationError('Maximum three categories are allowed.')
    
        return self.cleaned_data
```

`admin.py` - this remained the same:

```py
class ShowroomsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ShowroomsForm
    

admin.site.register(Showrooms, ShowroomsAdmin)
```

After that, it worked perfectly!